# Why when increasing the speed value more then 100 the speed is never change never increasing more then 100 and getting index out of bound?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At some point i'm getting in the inspector in the speed field this value :

[image: speed bug]

I'm also getting exception :

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Waypoints.Update () (at Assets/My Scripts/Waypoints.cs:24)

Line 24 :

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                waypoints[index], speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

The full script :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3[] waypoints;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;

    private int index = 0;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                waypoints[index], speed * Time.deltaTime);

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[index]);
            if (distance <= 0.1f)
            {
                index++;
            }

            if (index == waypoints.Length - 1)
            {
                index = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Unity is not Thread-safe which might let your `index` value be higher than `waypoints.Length - 1` at moment

You can try to use `lock` or `Interlocked` as below.

```
public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3[] waypoints;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;

    private int index = 0;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                waypoints[index], speed * Time.deltaTime);

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[index]);
            lock(_syncObj){
                if (distance <= 0.1f)
                {
                    index++;
                }

                if (index == waypoints.Length - 1)
                {
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By `Interlocked`

```
if (distance <= 0.1f)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref index);
}

if (index == waypoints.Length - 1)
{
    index = Interlocked.Exchange(ref index,0);
}
```